# replication postgres

Tags: postgresql, репликация

Есть два сервера, на обоих установлено postgresql 9.6, один из них мастер, второй слейв. Необходимо организовать репликацию таким образом. чтобы на слейве можно было создать базу данных, которой нет на мастере. Т.е. С мастера реплицируется БД1 в БД2 на слейве, они полностью идентичны, необходимо создать БД3 на слейве, которой не будет на мастере. Какие средства репликации могут мне помочь в этом? Спасибо.

Comment: Не понимаю, как наличие дополнительной БД на слейве может на что-то влиять... и при чём тут вообще репликация.

Comment: по умолчанию postgres реплицирует кластер целиком и не позволяет вносить какие-либо изменения на слейв. К примеру создать пользователя, которого нет на мастере, на слейве создать не получилось. После создания пользователя на мастере, он же появился на слейве.

Comment: Так то по умолчанию - потому как в основном репликацией решаются задачи анти-failover и balancing.

Answer (score 0):

средства репликации вам не помогут. Просто создайте параллельно новый кластер в другой data_directory и пишите в него...

организовать коммуникацию между slave базами и rw базой можно через `foreign data wrapper` или `dblink` или совсем брутально через fs с superuser правами.